# What is the characteristic of a ring that does not contain an identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does a ring without an identity element even have a characteristic?

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Is there a source that you can point me to that would have more information? Or can you elaborate?

Comment: I don't think anyone would publish this. We define [characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra)) for rings with unity.

Comment: @Ivan: the third paragraph of the Wikipedia article you link to explains how the definition can be generalized to non-unital rings in a natural way.

Answer (score 13):

One may define the characteristic of an abelian group $A$ to be the non-negative generator of the ideal $\mathrm{Ann}(A)$. Thus, we have $\mathrm{char}(A) \cdot A = 0$, and every other integer with this property is a multiple of $\mathrm{char}(A)$. This coincides with the usual definition of the characteristic of a ring when we consider its underlying additive group. As you see, we don't really need a unit, in fact no multiplication.

Comment: I expand the explanation a little more, for people who, like me, may need it: The abelian group A can be seen as a Z-module. Then Ann(A) is the biggest subset of Z that completely annihilates A. It can be checked that A is an ideal of Z, and thus, since Z is a PID, Ann(A)=nZ for some integer n. We define char(A)=n.