# Ring (without identity) of characteristic $n$ contains elements of any order $k$ dividing $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, rngs

Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring (i.e., may not have unity) with characteristic $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (positive integer) i.e any element added to itself $n$ times always yields additive identity $0$.

> Show that for any $k\mid n$, ring $R$ contains an element of order $k$.

If $km = n$, then for any $r\in R$ we have $kmr = k(mr) = 0$. So if we assume the order of $mr\in R$ to be $k'$ and assume also $k'< k$, then:
$$k'(mr) = (k'm)r = 0 $$

which Would contradict the choice of $n$, BUT, we don't have it established there necessarely exists an element of order $n$. (Such would exist, if $R$ was ring with identity).

It **would** seem obvious, since for all $a\in R$ we have $na = 0$, there has to be an element whose order is $n$, but is there?

Characteristic only provides that for every $a\in R$ $na = 0$, it doesn't exclude the possibility that for every $a\in R$ there exists $n'<n$ for which $n'a=0$. There is no contradiction.

We do have that the order of every element divides $n$. If $\mbox{ord} (a)=n'$, then $n'k=n$, though, not any closer to establishing the existence of $n$-th order element :<

Comment: Does $R$ have a unit $1$?

Comment: @AlexM. No, not necessarely. If it did, by definition this whole claim is trivial since $1$ is of $n$-th order.

Comment: You will have to use the minimality of $n$ somewhere, i.e. presumably you want add the condition that lcm of the orders of all elements is $n$.

Comment: When you say that $R$ is arbitrary, does this include the possibility of it being non-commutative?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, all we know is we have a ring with positive characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that in a ring without unity, of "characteristic" $n$, there must be an element of order $n$.

First, note: for a ring without unity, we must define the *characteristic* to be the minimum $n$ such that $nr = r$ for all $r$. (Equivalently, it's the LCM of the order of $r$ over all $r$ in the ring.) See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596000/what-is-the-characteristic-of-a-ring-that-does-not-contain-an-identity-element). Anyway this looks like the definition you're using, except you seem to have forgotten about the **minimum** part, which is critical if we want to conclude there's an element of order $n$.

Let's forget about the multiplication structure and just consider the underlying abelian group. Here is our theorem:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ be an abelian group. If $N = \text{LCM}(\{\text{order}(a) \mid a \in A\})$, then there exists an element $a \in A$ of order $N$.

*Proof.* First we show that if $a, b \in A$ have orders $m$ and $n$, and $m, n$ are relatively prime, then there is an element of order $mn$.
We can just take $a + b$. Notice that $mn(a+b)  = 0$,
so the order divides $mn$. If the order were smaller, WLOG we have $m'n(a+b) = 0$ where $m' < m$.
Now $(m'n)b = m'(nb) = 0$, so $(m'n)a = 0$, and since the order of $a$ is $m$, $m \mid m'n$. Since $m, n$ are relatively prime, $m \mid m'$, contradiction.

Now we can build an element of order $N$. Factorize $N$ as a product of prime powers: $N = p_1^{x_1} p_2^{x_2} \ldots p_k^{x_k}$. There is an element of order $p_i^{x_i}$ for each $i$: certainly there must be some element $r$ of order divisible by $p_i^{x_i}$, or $N$ would not be the LCM of all the orders, but then an appropriate multiple of $r$ has order $p_i^{x_i}$ exactly.
So we get elements $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_k$ whose orders are $p_i^{x_i}$.
Now we may apply the above result repeatedly (since the orders are relatively prime) to get an element of order $N$ -- in fact, it's just $r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_k$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik You're very welcome.